# Does Intercalation and Deintercalation of Lithium ions occurs in Half Cell?

Tags: electrochemistry

The important feature of Lithium ion batteries is the ability to  intercalate and deintercalate lithium ions in  anode and cathode . However when we use  half cell, using lithium metal foil as anode, intercalation and deintercalation process occurs in this case too. How the lithium ion moves and what process cause the current to flow in discharge?

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a lithium metal anode there is no intercalation really, just reduction of the lithium ions to lithium metal:

$$\ce{Li^+ + e^- -> Li^0_{(s)}} $$

The cathode reaction is still the same.